# triconsole calendar does not overlaps lower located calendar

Tags: php, javascript, css, calendar, datepicker

I use great calendar from http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php

One thing thats bothering me is when I have two calendars, one above another, and I activate (unfold) the top one with unfolding set to bottom. It should overlap the bottom one calendar, instead the bottom one (yet folded) actually overlaps the unfold one.

I understand this is hard to understand, so here is the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDgWN.png

How do you solve this behavior?

Comment: If you want us to tell you exactly what you need to change, you're going to need to post the code that you're using since it's different than what is displayed on the Calendar page you linked. It's most likely a z-index problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely to be in wrongly defined [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) CSS property. The "trigger" button should have lower z-index value than the calendar itself.
This is probably the calendar internal stylesheet's error.

Comment: You were right. I wrote to Triconsole and they confirmed that it was enough to add 
`$mycalendar->zindex = 2;`
to the upper calendar.
The number can be >=2 because 1 is default z-index value, so every other calendar have it.

I did not know this because it is/was not in functions list on their page.